# SAP .NET Connector 3.0 item not showing up in visual studio 08, 10, etc

Tags: .net, sap-dotnet-connector

I got the new SAP .NET connector 3.0 that is supposed to work for visual studio 2008 and 2010.  I just tried to create a C# console application and I went to the project menu to add a "new item" but I do not see an SAP Proxy item.  What am I missing ?

I am aware of the .NET connector 2.0 but I do not want the 2.0 version.  I've already seen the code project article etc., so please do not post a link to an article referencing the 2.0 version.  The whole purpose of SAP .NET connector 3.0 is to utilize vs 2010.

I've also taken the 2 DLL files from `C:\Program Files\SAP\SAPDotNet` (`sapnco.dll`, and `sapnco_utils.dll`) and referenced those files in my C# application.  I also have a reference to System.Web.Services.

I should be now able to right click my project and "Add Item" and one of those items should be an SAP Proxy object item...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3.0 connector doesn't work this way. From the documentation:

> With the .NET Connector 2.0, the NCo design time would generate a “proxy method”
>   for each ABAP function module you want to call, and one specific class for each
>   structure or table type that this function module is referencing. You had to create
>   objects from these structure/table classes and pass them into the proxy method
>   corresponding to the function module.
>
> **Now with the .NET Connector 3.0, there is no longer any kind of generated code.**

Good:

- No Visual Studio version dependency.
- Small changes in SAP function doesn't break the client.
- No generated code.

Bad:

- No auto completion. You have to read the function and datatype declarations. In SAP or in the debugger.

[Documentation and samples](http://service.sap.com/connectors).

Comment: I am new to this development. Could you please let me know to get the Documents and Samples ?